# I ran a npm run build, placed it on nodejs express.static, pm2 start app but Cannot GET '/'

Tags: node.js, linux, vue.js, amazon-ec2, pm2

I wanted to host 2 node app on one Linux box from AWS EC2. Where I can run a dev environment and staging environment. I noticed that I will have to use different ports on both of the apps but this is not the problem that I am facing.

Using the staging side which has always worked on the previous boxes that I have started it on to go first, making sure it works before trying out the different ports.

I have a backend node.js using express and a static webpage built with Vue CLI. Where the express app will use `app.use(express.static('static'));` to host the static webpage. Then proceed with hosting it on PM2 with `pm2 start /directoryToDist/main.js`. Once the daemon has started, I did a `curl http://localhost:80/` but it returns an error HTML page of `Cannot GET /`.

When I did `npm install`, `npm rebuild` and `npm build` on both apps. Made sure that the `dist` folder was built properly. Then did a `sudo -i` and `pm2 start /directoryToDist/main.js`. Making sure that a node app is running I did a `ps -ef | grep js` to show that it is running as so. There are no restarts on the pm2 mounted app and everything was running smoothly. I did the `curl http://localhost/` after and it did return `Cannot GET /`.

I did a zip file transfer of a working app in previous boxes and did the necessary installation of npm and run it. Expecting it to work like previous boxes but it didn't. showing the same error of `Cannot GET /`.

Node js build script

`"build": "rimraf dist/ && babel ./ --out-dir dist/ --ignore ./node_modules,./babelrc,./package.json,/.npm-debug-log,./static/* --copy-files"`

Vue js build script

`"build": "node build/build.js"`

Rebuild script that I use

```
cd api
npm run build
cd ..
cd pwa
npm run build
cd ..
sudo rm -rf api/dist/static
sudo mkdir -p api/dist/static
sudo cp -r pwa/dist/* api/dist/static/
sudo chown -R ubuntu.ubuntu *
```

Let me know if you need to see more

The actual result is to serve a proper `200` message on the curl before given a domain to the specific port.

Comment: So the path to your files is located at `ROOT/dist/static/*.*` ?

Comment: @MattOestreich yes `/home/ubuntu/nodeApp/dist/main.js` inside the main.js has a `app.use(express.static('static'))` that serves index.html

Comment: I believe it needs to be: `app.use(express.static('dist'))` in that case.. depending upon where your entry point is located for the Node app..

Comment: What does your `packages.json` file look like? Specifically "main"?

Comment: hmm I have tried it before. Well my `nodeApp` has a `dist` folder that has all the built files and then putting the built files of the `static nodeApp` front end side of it onto static subdirectory of `nodeApp`'s `dist` and run the main.js app on it.

Comment: @MattOestreich 
`"main": "main.js",`

`"scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist/ && babel ./ --out-dir dist/ --ignore ./node_modules,./babelrc,./package.json,/.npm-debug-log,./static/* --copy-files",`

Comment: You need to modify your packages.json to point to `main: "./dist/main.js`

Comment: Is your repo on Github?

Comment: @MattOestreich yes it is but it is not open to public. I am going to try putting `./dist/main.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that has worked.

Pm2 was not pointing to the current working directory. `sudo -i` and then running it `$ pm2 start /home/user/directory` will look for for module routes in the `directory` folder instead of the implemented `dist` folder.

So by solving this problem. One must traverse through the directory first and initiate the pm2 start there. `$ cd /home/user/directory/dist/` `$ pm2 start main.js`. This has served the node app well and stable.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can find it with `path`:

```
import path from 'path'

app.use(
  '/some-url',
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/some/path/on/server'))
)
```

If you know exact path on your server.

Relative paths works too:

```
app.use(
  '/some-url',
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../some/relative/on/server'))
)
```